# how to change submit button font on contact form

Tags: html, css, webforms

The 7th line from the end I tried to add in some CSS but it won't change the font on the button. Is there a way to do it in CSS or PHP? (Or maybe a way that actually works in HTML)

Thanks in advance! I'm really new at this.

here's my code:

```
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="something_sendform.php">
<table width="450px">
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top"">
  <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
 </td>

</tr>
<tr style="font-family:Orator Std">
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Try typing  'Orator Std '. If you are using font with name with space you have to use '  char.

Comment: Put that style property on the input tag....

Comment: Adding to what the person above me said, the `input` tag does not inherit styles from its parent. You must specify properties separately.

Comment: thanks guys, however I tried both and neither worked!

Comment: Does the font work elsewhere on the page? Perhaps you're not embedding the font correctly (if at all).

Comment: yeah I made a CSS document to change the font for the labels (email, telephone etc..) but the button for some reason won't change!

Comment: Could it be that I cannot style a button that is already linked to a PHP document? I looked through the PHP code and there is nowhere that I can even recognize a submit button in order to style it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `font-family` CSS property :

```
input[type=submit]{
    font-family: 'Orator Std';
}
```

To be all-browsers compatible, add `class="mysubmitbutton"` to your button, and use `input.mysubmitbutton` instead of `input[type=submit]`.

**Edit :** If you want to do this directly in the HTML code, do it on the `input` tag :

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" style="font-family:'Orator Std';" />
```

*I am not sure that Orator Std is a native CSS font though... For custom fonts usage in HTML/CSS, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144000/using-custom-fonts-using-css).*

Comment: I think Mac has a bug - it doesn't seem to honor the font. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28127184/font-size-of-html-form-submit-button-cannot-be-changed. But for whatever reason, if I _also_ change the font color and background color in my style, then it starts honoring the font.

Answer (score 1):

You're applying the styles on the wrong element. Try this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 25px;">
```

Note that that `Orator Std` is a custom font and if you want to use it, you'll have to download the font file and load it in your CSS using `@font-face`.

Also, using inline styles is generally regarded as a bad practice and it's best to apply the styles on `input[type=submit]` in your CSS file or inside the `<style>` tags. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/) question answers that in greater detail.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Dq3Mg/**