# How load my new fonts in html code

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I want to load a font in my CSS and/or HTML code. I need two fonts(bigsmalls-bold and lft-etica-web) but I don't find how download the font. I only I find a javascript code in

https://typekit.com

This javascript code I have to add in head of my html code.
I did it, but don't change my fonts. Could someone help me please?

Thank you so much

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using custom fonts using css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144000/using-custom-fonts-using-css)

Comment: could this link be useful? http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_fonts.asp

Answer (score 2):

Try using @font-face { url } in your css file. Uploading the font

Like this :

@font-face 
{
    font-family: myFirstFont; src: url('Sansation_Light.ttf'), url('Sansation_Light.eot');
}

The .eot is for IE9

Answer (score 0):

hai you have two options

1st one google font

2nd one CustomFonts

```
@font-face {
font-family: "MyCustomFonts";
src: local("MyCustomFonts"), url("../fonts/ArialNarrow.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

try this

Answer (score -1):

Typekit explains on there site how to install a font. Login, goto the kit editor and click [ embed code]

```
<script src="//use.typekit.net/YOUR_CODE_GOES_HERE.js"></script>
<script>try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
```

After you've done that:

> If you want to use Typekit in your CSS, click the “Using fonts in
>   CSS” link in the selectors area of your kit to reveal the appropriate
>   font-family names to use. Once you’ve included the Typekit embed code
>   in the  of your documents, you can add these font-family names
>   to the CSS rules in your own stylesheet:
>
> h1 {     font-family: "proxima-nova", sans-serif; }

http://help.typekit.com/customer/portal/articles/6859-working-with-css-selectors
**Using the font-family Names in Your CSS**

Comment: He already found the Javascript code as stated in the question.

Comment: Was going to update my answer, but something came up. Changed my answer with the additional info

Comment: Finally the only solution is pay. This font aren't free then typekit don't let you use it if you don't pay it. Thank you all