# How to add regional languages to our web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I refereed [This Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByGp7.png)  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByGp7.png): [how to use kannada font in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19423596/how-to-use-kannada-font-in-asp-net)
But i am unable to use the Kannada language in my page.I want to type Kannada in text box. [image: Kannada text Box]
But it is not happening... can any one tell me what may be the reason for that?

My source code is here:
forKannada.css file

```
  @font-face {font-family:RaghuKannada;
src: url('http://www.cdacmumbai.in/projects/indix/RaghuFonts/RORaghuKannada.ttf');}
```

home.aspx

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Home.aspx.cs" nherits="Home"  Culture="kn-IN" UICulture="kn-IN" %>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//kn-IN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="kn">
 <head runat="server">
<title></title>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link href="../CSS/forKannada.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<br />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />    
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Kannada"Font-Names="Tunga" />
&nbsp;
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Home.aspx.cs file

```
 public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
 ResourceManager rm;
 CultureInfo ci;
 static bool lkannda = false;
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 if (!IsPostBack)
 {
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
 rm = new     ResourceManager("Resources.Strings",System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("App_GlobalResources"))     ;
 ci = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
 LoadString(ci);
 }
 else
 {
 rm = new     ResourceManager("Resources.Strings",System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("App_GlobalResources")); 
 ci =Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
 LoadString(ci);
 }
 }
 private void LoadString(CultureInfo ci)
 {
 Label1.Text = rm.GetString("Name", ci);
 Label2.Text = rm.GetString("Desc", ci);
 Button1.Text = rm.GetString("AboutMe", ci);
 }
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 if(lkannda)
 {
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
 LoadString(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
 lkannda = false;
 }
 else
 {
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("kn-IN");
 LoadString(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
 lkannda = true;
 }
 }   
 }
```

and i created 2 resource files one for kannada and another for english with name Strings.kn-IN.resx and Strings.resx

Can any one tell me what is the error in this code. and how i can type kannada in textbox as image shows? and what else i need to add for this code?

Comment: Are you having the same problem in all browsers or in a specific one?

Comment: @codingstill I am trying with IE,Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome. same problem i am facing... i am using visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 2):

For taking user input in kannada, you can create a custom Text box control as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301832/Custom-Text-box-Control-that-Switch-keyboard-langu)

also you can get rid of resource files by using [google website Translator](https://translate.google.com/manager/website/) which translates your page on the fly. you just need to set you default language as Kannada