# Custom Font in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-2012

I have a little problem in visual studio 2013.
In my application (developed in html and javascript)
i use a custom font.
If i try to run my application 
on another pc (that didn't have installed  the font) it 
doesn't see the font. 
For this reason,obviously,i can't put my app in 
the windows store.

Maybe i have to setting some things in Visual studio?
This is the css code. Someone know what i have to do?

```
@font-face{
   font-family: 'custom_font';
   src: local('AngryBirds'), url('AngryBirds.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: why not host the font on a webserver / cdn and use the url rather than  relying on the font being on the local machine? This then means your app is dependant on an internet connection though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using custom fonts using css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144000/using-custom-fonts-using-css)

Answer (score 0):

The secret here is in the `src` property:

```
src: local('AngryBirds'), url('AngryBirds.ttf') format('truetype');
```

You need to either host the font at a remote location accessible via the internet then change the `url` entry to this location, or you need to locate the font at the location on the local system as specified under `local`.

Comment: I always  see applications that even if  don't use internet  have the custom font. For this reason i think that there is another solution.

Comment: I solved the problem. I changed the format of the font in .eot !