# Use of "Bliss Pro" font without downloading the font

Tags: css, fonts

I have a requirement to use font "Bliss Pro" for a product title. But it's not a standard windows font.
I have tried to search how can I use this font in my webpage, but did not found any online solution.

Is there any way I can use/include "Bliss Pro" font in my web page without downloading the font?

Appreciate your help....

Comment: http://fontdeck.com/typeface/bliss

Comment: To expand on @Christina's comment, you need to buy a license for the font through that website in order to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Generically, you can use a custom font using `@font-face` in your CSS. Here's a very basic example:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'YourFontName'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('http://domain.com/fonts/font.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}
```

Then, trivially, to use the font on a specific element:

```
.classname {
    font-family: 'YourFontName';
}
```

(`.classname` is your selector).

Note that certain font-formats don't work on all browsers; you can use [fontsquirrel.com](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)'s generator to avoid too much effort converting.

You can find a nice set of free web-fonts provided by [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts) (also has auto-generated CSS `@font-face` rules, so you don't have to write your own).

> while also preventing people from having free access to download the font, if possible

Nope, it isn't possible to style your text with a custom font embedded via CSS, while preventing people from downloading it. You need to use images, Flash, or the [HTML5 Canvas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element), all of which aren't very practical.

I hope that helped!

**[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144000/using-custom-fonts-using-css)**