# Print HTML page using "FontA11" of EPSON

Tags: css, printing, fonts, epson

I want to print my HTML page from browser using the fonts "FontA11". How can I use this fonts for my page?

I want to print this using browser. I am going to make web app for my client and they are using EPSON printer to print.

I have set my Epson (TM-U220D, Model: M188D) printer as default and I am able to see the fonts "FontA11" in Microsoft word. It also prints using this fonts when printed from Microsoft word.

Now, I want to print my HTML page from browser using this fonts but its not working. I have also tried NOT setting "font-family" to my css and check which fonts it takes but even that is not working.

I know "FontA11" is printer fonts and we can't refer those in HTML page but I want a way through which my page outputs with "FontA11" fonts.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144000/using-custom-fonts-using-css

Comment: If you claim that you know FontA11 can't be referred to in HTML, can you explain why you know that? Is it not an OpenType (`ttf` or `otf`) font? If not, what kind of font is it? If word can find it, it lives in `windows\fonts` so it's a file on your drive, what kind of file is it?

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans: As I have written in the question, **FontA11** are printer fonts and there is no (**ttf** or **otf**) file for these fonts. When we set EPSON printer as default printer, we can see the fonts in word else those are not shown in word. You can read more for why its shown in word [here](http://sandstorm36.blogspot.in/2012/09/proper-fonts-for-dot-matrix-printers.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am using EPSON TM T82, Windows 7, Internet Explorer, and these steps would work for me.

Devices and Printer>Printing Preferences>Printer Settings>True Type Font Substitution>Substitute>Advanced Settings>Tick Substitute All>Set Device Font Name>OK>Apply.

Google Chrome will not work for me.

Answer (score -2):

Save the page to disk, open it in Word, ctrl-A to select everything, change font to FONT11A, print?

Comment: It will not work for me because I need to deliver this to client and client will not do as you said. I want to print that using browser.

Comment: please put that detail in your question, then. Also, why would your client have the exact same printer? That makes no sense. And if the anwer is "they might not, but I want it to look like my printer's font" then why not just find a normal opentype font that looks similar and use that on your page.

Comment: I am going to make app for my client and they are using EPSON printers in their store for printing. I hope you can understand now.

Comment: please put that in your problem description instead of leaving that as comment here. We can't help you properly unless you give *all* the details in your post.

Comment: The question was "Print HTML page from browser"

Comment: That is not a question. "Even how do I print a page in my browser" isn't a question for StackOverflow (browsers have printing built in). You question actually talks about fonts, so you don't want to know how to print, you already know how to do that, you have problems with something else: [be specific and show code](/help/how-to-ask), and make sure you're [on topic for SO](/help/on-topic)