# CSS : custom font by using @font-face

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, fonts

i just downloaded a font that is otf type  `Sintony-Bold.otf` placed it inside the fonts folder and  in  style.css i am using this rule

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'custom'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url(../fonts/Sintony-Bold.otf); /*URL to font*/
}
```

and then using this font-family like this

```
font-family: 'custom';
```

but problem is that this is not giving any effect  , when i try t inspect it gives me pt serif , or some other fonts , i'm using bootstrap how do i fix this issue , Please help

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144000/using-custom-fonts-using-css?

Comment: you can use font-squirrel generator  http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator , it will produce and convert your font for a full support (100% commercial use)

Comment: in fact, sintony is [already available](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/sintony) from font-squirrel. With that said, "is not giving any effect" is not useful: which browser(s)? What does the browser say is happening. Is there a 404 for the font? An error parsing the font before loading? Bad CSS before the @font-face? You're on the hook for looking for all the debug information first, and if, with that information, you can't figure it out, SO is a great place to ask. But not before. Without that data, you forgot the source format value.