# Gulp File Not Copying Fonts

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

I am attempting to move some of my fonts over through my resources/assets/fonts/web-icons/ directory over so that when I use them in my layouts it will show the correct icons. Can someone help me understand when I run this for my gulp file it does not copy the web-icons over to the public folder which I'm trying to show as public/fonts/web-icons.

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir(function (mix) {

    /**
     * Copy needed files from Remark directories
     * to /public directory.
     */
    mix.copy('fonts/web-icons', 'public/fonts');

    mix.styles([
        'libs/bootstrap.css',
        'libs/bootstrap-extend.css',
        'libs/animsition.css',
        'libs/asScrollable.css',
        'libs/switchery.css',
        'libs/slidePanel.css',
        'libs/flag-icon.css',
        'site.min.css'
    ]);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Elixir documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/elixir#copying-files-and-directories):

> The copy method may be used to copy files and directories to new locations. All operations are **relative to the project's root directory**

If your fonts are stored in your `resources` directory, you should specify that full path as the first argument:

```
mix.copy('resources/assets/fonts/web-icons', 'public/fonts/web-icons');
```

Comment: That's great. however what if I have more than one directories of fonts like a font awesome directory as well. I'm assuming I would copy those over too just the same way. Is that correct? Also would I just make two calls two each file in my layout file for the icons or is it possible with Elixir to group all fonts together in one file or can I even put those into an additional file with all my other css?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to copy multiple files over to the same directory if you want. Just make multiple `mix.copy()` calls. Font files are not designed to be combined into a single file. You'll have to reference them individually in your CSS file(s) as you normally would.

Comment: What do you mean by that second part? How would I work that into Elixir?

Comment: Using custom font files requires two steps: 1) adding the font files to your website (which you are doing by copying them from resources/ to public/), and 2) adding the custom fonts to your CSS via [`@font-face`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144000/using-custom-fonts-using-css). The latter you do not need Elixir for.

Comment: Use @font-face even when the fonts have CSS files I was going to old? Or should I import the CSS files?

Comment: You can import the CSS files if your font package comes with them. Make sure to either move those to your public/ directory also, or compile them with your project's styles if you are using LESS/SASS.