# CSS: Use Chinese font

Tags: html, css

How do I use chinese fonts in css?

I found a particular website but I'm not sure how to download it and use it:
http://en.justfont.com/fontdetail/171

I'm looking at the free fonts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using custom fonts using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144000/using-custom-fonts-using-css)

Comment: I know what fontface and I use it for a ton of custom fonts, that's probably the same way it's used for international font but I haven't been able to find how to use another website for custom chinese font

Comment: did answer given work for you?

Comment: I think so but how did you get it to work I'm confused, what url did you go to?

Answer (score 1):

You can download this font from URL give below and can apply the style sheet.

http://cdn-go.justfont.com/file/jfont.woff?k=07877935b38c6cac6a7cab4903a39ade&n=xingothic-tc-w2&o=http%3A%2F%2Fen.justfont.com&p=1165

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "xingothic-tc-w8";
    font-weight: 800;
    src: local(" "), url("http://cdn-go.justfont.com/file/jfont.woff?k=3e8dfe1ef3dae2a9c3bfc4a40f4c7295&n=xingothic-tc-w8&o=http%3A%2F%2Fen.justfont.com&p=1165") format("woff");
}
```

Thanks