# Google font not loading in CSS stylesheet

Tags: html, css, fonts, loading

Importing the '`Droid Arabic Naskh`' early accesss Google font into my CSS stylesheet, however, no matter how I import it, it doesn't appear to load. *I'm currently using **XAMPP localhost** for this.*

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/droidarabicnaskh.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

**CSS**

```
a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #406e8e;
    font-family: 'Droid Arabic Naskh', serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not right to link the used font using a html link tag. It is not for that purpose.
Instead use css. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38198094/how-to-install-custom-fonts-in-css) is a question similar to yours.

Comment: The link provided suggests using the HTML link tag.

Comment: Yes, link tag to the CSS, but not to the file of the font.

Comment: The font's CSS is in fact linked (unless I'm misunderstanding) in the HTML. The font file itself is not linked at all from here.