# How to add custom font to SharePoint online?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sharepoint

I want to apply a custom font to my custom SharePoint master page.
I have tried to create a new font-scheme, but the problem is that the font is a custom one.

Is there any solution on how to apply custom fonts to SharePoint custom master pages?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which version of sharepoint you are using.  But in 2013 you can create a ["theme" which uses a color palette, and a font scheme.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945889.aspx)

Specifically check out the [webfonts section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945889.aspx#webFont)

That is the proper way to do sharepoint branding.  You could also use css for each page and include a global css file in the master page that would have the custom font.  You just need to have the [url of the font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144000/using-custom-fonts-using-css).

Comment: i did it but the problem is that i have a custom font dinpro, when i create a new fontscheme ,it doesn't work on my custom master page

Comment: if you want to use a theme you have to "To specify a web font, you must provide the URL to your web font files in four font formats (for support across browsers), and a small and large thumbnail image to use to render the font names in the font scheme picker."

Otherwise you can upload the font file to your server and then use css to set the font-family like in SO question i posted.

Comment: @font-face {


    font-family: 'YourFontName'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('http://domain.com/fonts/font.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}
Then, trivially, to use the font on a specific element:

.classname {
    font-family: 'YourFontName';
}

Comment: this method work just a fine , but i'm looking for a solution to create a custom font scheme using a web font ,
i tried to upload my fonts src and create a custom font scheme using myfonts src :


    <s:fontSlots>
        <s:fontSlot name="title">
            <s:latin typeface="din1451alt" eotsrc="/_catalogs/theme/15/din1451alt.eot" woffsrc="/_catalogs/theme/15/din1451alt.woff" ttfsrc="/_catalogs/theme/15/din1451alt.ttf" svgsrc="/_catalogs/theme/15/din1451alt.svg" largeimgsrc="" smallimgsrc="" />
but it doesn't work

Comment: You left out large and small img src.  Have you tried filling those fields in and seeing if you can upload it to the fonts library? "To specify a web font, you must provide the URL to your web font files in four font formats (for support across browsers), and a small and large thumbnail image to use to render the font names in the font scheme picker."  It says must, this wouldnt be the first time sharepoint has required everything needed to be filled out before you could use it.