# Using Custom font in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I am using the Atom editor with my Mac and have a problem. I need to put the "Typogrotesk" font in my website. I have been trying to do this for a while, but have had no luck. I have tried using this as my CSS code, but no luck:

```
h1 {
font-family: "Typogrotesk";
font-size: 300%;
color: white
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using custom fonts using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144000/using-custom-fonts-using-css)

Comment: You need to link to it in your `<head>` or install the font in a folder on your machine

Comment: If an answer helped you, make sure to upvote and/or accept it!

Comment: @Jerfov2 - Yep! I just tried it, and it worked :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a font face:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Typogrotesk'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('TheURLToTheFontFile'); /*URL to font*/
}
```

Then to use it in your css styling:

```
.example {
    font-family: 'Typogrotesk';
}
```

Credit: @Chris at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144000/using-custom-fonts-using-css)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Typogrotesk";
    src: url(yourfontfile);
}
```

Put this in your CSS to import the font.  You should be able to use the font elsewhere.

If that doesn't work, you may need to try `yourfontfile` in single or double quotes.

Comment: This answer helped me too, but I am only allowed to except one :(

Answer (score 1):

Download it here: http://www.dafont.com/de/typo-grotesk.font

Upload it to a folder on your webspace. For example: "styles/fonts"

On the top of your style.css you add the following code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Typogrotesk";
    src: url(fonts/typogrotesk.ttf);
}
```

After that you define it for a single element

```
.yourclass {
font-family: 'Typogrotesk';
}
```

or you define it for all elements

```
* {
font-family: 'Typogrotesk';
}
```