# How do I reference a custom font file in my asset folder?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts, ruby-on-rails-5, assets

With Rails 5, how do I reference a custom font file I have uploaded?  I have placed the file in

```
app/assets/fonts/chicagoflf-webfont.woff
```

Then in my CSS file, I have

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'chicagoflfregular';
    src: url('fonts/chicagoflf-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/chicagoflf-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

but I don't see that the font is loading, even after restarting my server.  What is the proper path I should be using in my "url" field?

Comment: Have you done precompile of assets? May be thats why its not picking up?

Comment: No I haven't.  Is that necessary?  Are you sayhing the path is right?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905905/using-fonts-with-rails-asset-pipeline

Comment: Also, you could use a service like FontSquirrel to generate more font formats for other browser to have better support

Comment: What is your css file name extension? It it css or scss?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using custom fonts using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144000/using-custom-fonts-using-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using **Sass**, you can use either use `font-url` or `asset-url` to call your font. And considering you placed your custom fonts in `app/assets/fonts`, you should be able to call the fonts **directly with no prefix in the path** like so

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'chicagoflfregular';
  src: font-url('chicagoflf-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       font-url('chicagoflf-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

**or**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'chicagoflfregular';
  src: asset-url('chicagoflf-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       asset-url('chicagoflf-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

**or**

If you are **not using Sass**, then with using `url` you should able to call the font with prefix `assets` not `fonts` like so

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'chicagoflfregular';
  src: url('/assets/chicagoflf-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('/assets/chicagoflf-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

And if you haven't pre-compiled your assets, your **fonts won't appear**. So you need to pre-compile the assets. For example for production environment do

```
RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails assets:precompile
```

and don't forget to **restart the server**

Comment: I wasn't using sass but renaming my file to application.css.scss and applying your suggestions caused my font faces to show up.  Thank you!

Comment: @Natalia By using saas i mean the file extension is `.scss` or .`css.scss`. Anyways I'm glad it worked. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `font_url` helper instead of `url`

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'chicagoflfregular';
  src: font_url('fonts/chicagoflf-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       font_url('fonts/chicagoflf-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

[AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-font_url](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-font_url) from official docs

**UPDATE**
Did you added fonts folder `in config/application.rb`?

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ...
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
    config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried this but despite the fact that "ls app/assets/fonts/chicagoflf-webfont.woff2" returns the path to the font from my command line, I don't see the font using your code above.

Answer (score 0):

Add the fonts path to the `assets` path as below:

**config/initializers/assets.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')

# Fonts
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|woff2|ttf)\z/
```

Then, you can change the **`css`** file to **`css.erb`** file and then you can use rails helper methods `font_path` or `asset_path` for specifying the font URL in `src` as below:

**custom.css.erb**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'chicagoflfregular';
    src: url("<%= asset_path('chicagoflf-webfont.woff2') %>") format('woff2'),
         url("<%= asset_path('chicagoflf-webfont.woff') %>") format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Please make sure you have precompiled the assets in **production** environment.