# How to make this effect please

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying to make this under construction page with this special effect.i
 mean the strip line on every letter.i am learning web design so please
 help me to make this effect.

[image]

i have no idea how to make this either using CSS or JS!

Comment: That's a custom font face

Comment: minzkraut what is custom font face and i use them in my project?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a coding question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144000/using-custom-fonts-using-css

Answer (score 1):

It's not a special CSS or JS effect. It's a custom font.

Use a web font like this : https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Bungee+Inline

To embed your selected fonts into a webpage, copy this code into the  of your HTML document.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee+Inline" rel="stylesheet">
```

Use the following CSS rule to specify this family:

```
font-family: 'Bungee Inline', cursive;
```

For examples of how fonts can be added to webpages, see the [getting started guide](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started).

Comment: can you please add something more , this answer is popping up in **Low Quality Posts** although i understand there is nothing much to explain here.

Comment: Fair enough, I have added more explanation from Google font's site.

Comment: yeah that looks good