# CSS does not recognise custom font

Tags: css, fonts

Following the example given in this [other stackovervlow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144000/using-custom-fonts-using-css), I have the problem that it seems my css does not recognise the font and just fills in a different one.

[Font I want to use](https://www.1001fonts.com/libel-suit-font.html)

CSS file

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'libelsuit'; /*a name to be used later*/
src: url('https://ff.static.1001fonts.net/l/i/libel-suit.regular.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}

.order
{
    font-family: 'libelsuit';
}
```

Comment: You need to download `libel-suit.regular.ttf` font on your machine or hosting and that path in `src`.

Comment: I tried that, then I placed the path in the place where you'd put the url and it did not seem to work either

Comment: `@font-face {
    font-family: 'libelsuit'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: 'libel-suit-rg.ttf'; /*URL to font*/
}` 

Did not work, neither did 

`@font-face {
    font-family: 'libelsuit'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('/libel-suit-rg.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}`

Comment: Is `libelsuit` webfont?

Comment: I think that might be the problem! Thank you!