# Use Century Gothic or other fonts on website

Tags: html, css

I'm very inexperienced on working with CSS and HTML.
I'm building an website and I'd like to use Century Gothic font - but I don't know how to "import it".

How can I do it?

Answer (score 13):

If you're specifically looking for the Century Gothic font then one option would be to use Adobe's hosted version of it in the following `link` tag. If you're looking to import other fonts then reference this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144000/using-custom-fonts-using-css).

```css
html { 
  font-family: century-gothic, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/oov2wcw.css">
</head>
  This is Century Gothic
</html>
```

Comment: The user clearly said _but I don't know how to "import it"._ he/she needs to import it. These are system fonts. You should import them first and then use them