# CSS Web safe fonts

Tags: html, css, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am developing my portfolio & for that, I plan to make a stylish NAV bar. I am using ReactJs. The problem is I made a logo of my name using Web safe fonts so that the logo will look the same over all the browsers & machines.

It worked for my Windows **1st PC** (chrome)machine and MAC (safari) machine [screenshot of that logo for machine 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzrFa.png), but in another Windows **2nd PC** machine(chrome & edge) it looks completely different & so simple text [screenshot of that logo for machine 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXDyT.png). I don't want this simple logo.

In the CSS file, I used this - **Brush Script MT** font family. So is there any process that I can manually import Brush Script MT - this font family file into my project so that universally it'll be the same?

Besides Is there any other process to fix this issue?

JSX code snippet -

```
<div className="n-left">
        <div className="n-name">Titas</div>
</div>
```

CSS code snippet-

```
.n-left{
    flex: 1;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    gap: 3rem;
}

.n-name{
    
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: Brush Script MT;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #d81313,#d61aad,#b135d6);
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-clip: text;

}
```

Comment: Import the actual font files or use a cross-browser font stack. That should help ensure consistent text rendering!

Comment: You can [import any font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144000/using-custom-fonts-using-css), however be wary of the licenses attached, some fonts have a reasonably large fee for commercial use (which your portfolio may count as, depending on the content)

Comment: If this logo is the _only_ thing you need this font for though, then adding a full web font would be overkill. In that case you should either create a "reduced" font that contains only the necessary glyphs (to save on font "file" size") ... or use a different technique altogether (f.e., implement your logo as an SVG.)

Comment: The term web-safe-fonts is just misleading it doesn't mean a font is available on all plattforms. We shouldn't use this term any longer - most of these fonts are not included in any android system. I agree with CBroe rebuild your logo in an editor like inkscape and save it as  svg. You can also convert all text to paths. This way the logo will definitely look the same on every device.