How to change fonts in form-io?
I am creating a form in an RTL language in Form-io. I am aware that there's a specific element called HTML element that can be assigned attributes. Attributes can be defined as below:
| **key** | **value** |
|---------|----------|
| dir     | rtl      |
| align   | right    |

But when I try adding a font-family attribute, it won't work. I have also tried modifying the custom CSS by adding a class name, say sample and the class style definition as below:
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Vazirmatn-Black';
    src: url('https://github.com/rastikerdar/vazirmatn/blob/master/fonts/ttf/Vazirmatn-Black.ttf');
}
.sample {
    font-family: 'Vazirmatn-Black';
}

It doesn't work. Any ideas?
PS: Keep the solution simple because it is going to be applied on every single element in the forms.

In generic CSS: You have to source Vazirmatn font first. If there is no such font in user computer, than it will not be displayed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144000/using-custom-fonts-using-css

Does this answer your question? Using custom fonts using CSS?

@Justinas I have tried defining custom CSS fonts and providing sources. It just doesn't work. I was hoping I could find a way to resolve the issue using the key-value table of attributes.
