What is the correct way to set custom font with bold or italic (etc.) iterations?
Let's say I need to put a custom font on my website.
I have this font, let's say it's called "Aphias". I use this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43366402/3536236 and have the CSS thus:
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Aphias';
    src: url('/assets/fonts/Aphias.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('/assets/fonts/Aphias.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

Ok, but the font I have has lots of separate files for different iterations, such as a Bold file and an italic file.
My font directory contains:

Aphias.ttf
Aphias.woff
Aphias-Bold.ttf
Aphias-Bold.woff
Aphias-Italic.ttf
Aphias-Italic.woff

What is the correct way to add these iterations to the CSS so that - for example; the <strong></strong> version of the font is loaded at the correct time, or when a text is marked as font-weight: bold; that the bold iteration is displayed:
Eg


    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Aphias';
        src: url('/assets/fonts/Aphias.woff') format('woff'), 
             url('/assets/fonts/Aphias.ttf') format('truetype');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
    
    
    p {
        font-family: 'Aphias', Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 1rem;
    }

    p > span {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    
    
<p>
This is some text with the custom font on display. Loaded from the font file. 

<span>This is the same text but should be bold / heavy font.</span></p>



The only way I think I can do it is with multiple @font-faces but they don't seem to work.
eg
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Aphias';
    src: url('/assets/fonts/Aphias.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('/assets/fonts/Aphias.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Aphias Italic';
    src: url('/assets/fonts/Aphias-Italic.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('/assets/fonts/Aphias-Italic.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Aphias Bold';
    src: url('/assets/fonts/Aphias-Bold.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('/assets/fonts/Aphias-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}

I can't find any documentation on this specific issue. How do I get this to work? The similar question here: Defining CSS @Font-Face bold italic answers don't actually answer the question asked.

You're almost there. Have multiple @font-face declarations, but change them all to have the same font-family: "Aphias";

+1 to what @Kosh said. If you have different font-names for different types of the same font, you will have to set the fonts explicitly for all the elements that have font browser styles. Otherwise, you may end up with a font that you don't expect (the browser will try to bold/italicize the regular font instead of using the proper one).

@Kosh thanks. I was believing the duplicate font name was going to overwrite the previous. Thanks for the clarifier.

The way to use the same font in different variations is to define its own -@font-face for each type, and call them all the same name in font-family.
Then in your use of the font - if you define in CSS for example: font-style: italic;
then the browser will know to go to the font that is of type italic,
and according to your example, it will look like this:
@font-face {
font-family: 'Aphias';
src: url('/assets/fonts/Aphias.woff') format('woff'),
url('/assets/fonts/Aphias.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'Aphias';
src: url('/assets/fonts/Aphias-Italic.woff') format('woff'),
 url('/assets/fonts/Aphias-Italic.ttf') format('truetype');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
 font-family: 'Aphias';
 src: url('/assets/fonts/Aphias-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
 url('/assets/fonts/Aphias-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
 font-weight: bold;
 font-style: normal;
}

And when you want to use the font in a specific way, for example with bold, you do it like this:
<p>
This is some text with the custom font on display. Loaded from the font file.

<span>This is the same text but should be bold / heavy font.</span></p>

p {
 font-weight: bold; 
}

This will load the bold version of 'Aphias'.
